# ListCollectionView to List

Tags: c#

I have a ListCollectionView that I would like to put into a List, but I'm unsure how to do this.
Below is the code that I have tried.  It returns an error that ListCollectionView
 does not contain a definition for ToList().

```
   var repItems = (ListCollectionView)view;
   var listItems = repItems.ToList();
```

Can anyone show me how?

Comment: would this([link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8368168f-d5e6-4336-9f62-a7911af93d2c/how-to-get-an-ilist-from-a-listcollectionview?forum=csharpgeneral)) solution work?

Comment: Thanks for the link Drg0nvil, it is useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this.Instead of using List use IList

```
var repItems = (ListCollectionView)view;
IList<object> list = repItems.SourceCollection as IList<object>;
```

Comment: .SourceCollection returns the unfiltered collection. What if I want the same filtered results in a list ?

Comment: totally agree with comment

Answer (score 1):

ListCollectionView implements non-generic IEnumerable so you can't call generic ToList extension method on it. You need to cast it first:

```
var repItems = (ListCollectionView)view;
listItems = repItems.Cast<object>().ToList();
```